# How to Set Dynamically Coordinates For detail band element in Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a jasper report in which i have total 3 bands.
- Title Band
- Detail Band
- Page Footer Band
 I have to set all band's element dynamically.
For Title Band i am setting coordinates like,

```
JRDesignTextField jrDesignTextField = (JRDesignTextField) jasperDesign.getTitle().getElementByKey(elementKey);
        if (Validator.isNotNull(jrDesignTextField)) {
            jrDesignTextField.setX(x);
            jrDesignTextField.setY(y);
        }
```

and i have tried to set coordinates for detail band element like,

```
JRDesignTextField jrDesignTextField = (JRDesignTextField) jasperDesign.getDetailSection().getBands()[0].getElementByKey(elementKey);
            if (Validator.isNotNull(jrDesignTextField)) {
                jrDesignTextField.setX(x);
                jrDesignTextField.setY(y);
            }
```

but it is not working for detail band.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: `but it is not working for detail band` - What does it mean? Do you have some exception? Or condition in if returns false?

Comment: @AlexK..it is not giving any error but it also not giving me the element  and returns null.

Comment: Looks strange. You should post the small sample to reproduce the problem: small *jrxml* and full piece of *Java* code.